# Debezium Connector tries to open old log file

Tags: apache-kafka, debezium, logminer

I have a debezium connector that works fine, for a limited time. These errors occur in log file:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00308: cannot open archived log '+RECO/XXXXXXXX/ARCHIVELOG/2022_01_04/thread_1_seq_53874.3204.1093111215'
ORA-17503: ksfdopn:2 Failed to open file +RECO/XXXXXXXX/ARCHIVELOG/2022_01_04/thread_1_seq_53874.3204.1093111215
ORA-15012: ASM file '+RECO/XXXXXX/ARCHIVELOG/2022_01_04/thread_1_seq_53874.3204.1093111215' does not exist
```

I've learnt in this database log files are deleted daily. Is my connector trying to read an old log file, which does not exist anymore? How can I tell my connector to check only last 12 hours, for example. Or should I do something in database side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I've learnt in this database log files are deleted daily. Is my connector trying to read an old log file, which does not exist anymore?

It is fine to delete archive logs that are no longer needed, but it's critical that you make sure that you are not deleting logs that the Oracle Connector still requires in order to perform mining.  In your particular case, the connector still required `thread_1_seq_53874.3204.1093111215` but the log is no longer on the file system and therefore the connector will stop with an error.  This error happens with any other connector such as MySQL if you remove the binlogs before the connector is done reading them.

> How can I tell my connector to check only last 12 hours, for example.

You cannot.

The way the Debezium connectors are designed is that they're meant to read **all** changes from the logs in chronological order to guarantee that there is no change data event loss. If a log were to be deleted that was needed and we did not throw an error, then you would have gaps where changes from the source database would not be represented as change events and so your consumers wouldn't be kept in sync.

> Or should I do something in database side

Archive logs need to be retained for as long as they're needed by the connector.  The latency of the Oracle connector is dependent both on the volatility of your database but also on a number of factors such as the performance of the database server hardware (disk and cpu), the size of your redo logs, etc.

Some environments may not be able to keep archive logs available in the default destination location for extended periods of time due to space constraints.  This is why we introduced a way that you can set up Oracle to write archive logs to a secondary destination location that is capable of retaining the logs for a longer period of time, often via a network mount, and then you can explicitly tell the connector use that archive destination name rather than the first valid/default location of the system.

Comment: thanks for the clear explanation. so, I'll try to keep log files a little longer before they get deleted.

Comment: The Oracle connector does expose JMX metrics and one metric we expose is the offset SCN, which is the low watermark point where the connector must continue to operate from.  You can use this SCN value in conjunction with some SQL to determine the sequence cut-off point where you can ask RMAN to only delete logs older than said sequence.  This has the benefit if automated to avoid a situation where if the connector is down, you don't accidentally delete logs that may be needed when the connector is restarted.